# Alguien sabe porque no puedo hacer que mi código funcione y mi personaje se mueva

Tags: unity

Soy nueva y estoy aprendiendo y no se como continuar para que mi personaje camine recto si lo había conseguido pero al agregar mas código las nuevas líneas de código desactivan las anteriores y ya no se como resolverlo.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Controles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float velocidad;
    private Rigdbody2D rigdbody;

    private void Start() 
    {
        rigdbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ProcesarMovimiento();
    }
    void ProcesarMovimiento() 
    {
        //Logica de movimiento.
        float inputMovimiento = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(inputMovimiento * velocidad, rigidbody.velocity.y);

    }
}
```